# Geometric Network error in File Geodatabase<Network Dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-class, file-geodatabase, geometric-network, network-dataset

I need to create a geometric network in my network dataset which resides within my file geodatabase. I have been receiving the following error: Cannot create geometric network. *The selected feature dataset does not contain any feature classes which can participate in a new geometric network.*

This error should not come up because there are tons of functional feature classes in the network data set.

Any workarounds or solutions?

Comment: Are you sure you are creating a geometric network with a network dataset? Did you mean feature dataset?

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Feature Dataset in your database.
copy the Feature Classes you want to use to this Feature Dataset
Right klick on the newly created Feature Dataset and select /new/Geometric Network.

And read the ESRI article
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/in_ArcCatalog/002r00000009000000/

Comment: I think you should check your terminology with respect to features, feature classes and feature datasets.